# Javascript Timeout with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

i have some problems with my setTimeout and setInterval functions. What i need to do is displaying an ad 2 seconds after the app was launched and then display it every 2 minutes. 
Good, untill now i managed to do the first half of the problem (display it after 2 seconds) but i can't figure it out how to delay the timeout with another 2 minutes and execute it in a loop (probably with setInterval).
I tried adding another timeout in this timeout but it delays the first execution.

I would apreciate some help.
Here is my code untill now:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        // this will create a banner on startup
        AdMob.createBanner( {
          adId: admobid.banner,
          position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
          overlap: false,
          offsetTopBar: false,
          bgColor: 'black'
        } );

        // this will load a full screen ad on startup
        AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
          adId: admobid.interstitial,
          autoShow: true
        });
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: Did you try adding the set interval inside the set timeout already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to call the same code after 2 seconds and then again every 2 minutes, you can do that like this:

```
function someAdCode() {
    // put the code here that you want to repeat
}

// start it in 2 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    someAdCode();
    // schedule it to repeat every 2 minutes
    setInterval(someAdCode, 2 * 60 * 1000);
}, 2000);
```

This uses a `setTimeout()` for the one-time 2 second delay.  Then, in that callback, you start the `setInterval()` to repeat every 2 minutes.